# Tangent vector of vector space

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-topology, tangent-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a 2 dimensional real vector space. Then, there exists an linear isomorphism $x:\,V\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2$. For any pairs of bases $\mathcal V=(v_1,v_2)$ of $V$ and $\mathcal B=(e_1,e_2)$ of $\mathbb R^2$, we define
\begin{align}
\big[x\big]_{\mathcal V,\mathcal B} = \begin{bmatrix}
\big[x(v_1)\big]_{\mathcal B} & \big[x(v_2)\big]_{\mathcal B} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
to be the matrix representation of $x$ respect to the bases $\mathcal V,\,\mathcal B$. In this topic, we will consider $\mathcal B$ to be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2 $.

Moreover, each isomorphism is also a diffeomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb R^2$. From there, if $T$ is a tangent vector at $p\in V$, then there exists a smooth curve $\alpha:\,I\longrightarrow V$ such that $p=\alpha(t_0)$ and
\begin{align}
\\ T\,&=\,(x\circ\alpha)_1'(t_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial u_1}\bigg|_p + (x\circ\alpha)_2'(t_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial u_2}\bigg|_p 
\newline T(f)\,&=\,(x\circ\alpha)_1'(t_0)\frac{\partial\big(f\circ x^{-1}  \big) }{\partial u_1}\big(x(p)\big) + (x\circ\alpha)_2'(t_0)\frac{\partial\big(f\circ x^{-1}  \big) }{\partial u_2}\big(x(p)\big)\tag1
\end{align}
for all $f\in C^\infty(p) $.

However, since $x:\, V\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2$ is linear, we can write
\begin{align}
x(p) = x\big(p_1v_1+p_2v_2 \big)=p_1x(v_1)+p_2x(v_2).\tag2
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}
\big(x\circ\alpha\big)(t)&=x\big(\alpha(t)\big)=\alpha_1(t)e_1+\alpha_2(t)e_2
\newline (x\circ\alpha)_1'(t_0) &= \alpha_1'(t_0)
\newline (x\circ\alpha)_2'(t_0) &= \alpha_2'(t_0).\tag3
\end{align}
Now, I wonder if this fact is true
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\left[\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial u_1}\bigg|_p \right]_{\mathcal C} & \left[\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial u_2}\bigg|_p \right]_{\mathcal C}
\end{pmatrix}= \big[x\big]_{\mathcal V,\mathcal B}\tag4
\end{align}
where $\mathcal C$ is some basis of $TV_p$ ? And if we consider the differential at $p$
\begin{align}
dx_p:\ TV_p & \longrightarrow \mathbb R^2
\newline T & \longmapsto dx_p(T)\tag5
\end{align}
since $dx_p$ is a linear isomorphism, then does the its representation matrix is the same to $\big[x\big]_{\mathcal V,\mathcal B} $ for some pair of bases ?

Thanks.

Comment: I find your line of thought a little confusing. But whatever you are asking should follow from "Given a chart $x\colon M\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $p\in M$, the vectors $\partial_{u_i}(p)\in T_pM$ are defined (can be defined) as the ones which are mapped to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ via the linear isomorphism $dx_p\colon T_pM\to\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @HudsonLima if $\mathcal B$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^m$, then $\mathcal A=(dx_p)^{-1}(\mathcal B)$ is a basis of $TM_p$, and 
\begin{align}
\big[\partial_{u_i}\big|_p \big]_{\mathcal A} = \big[dx_p( \partial_{u_i}\big|_p  ) \big]_{\mathcal B}.
\end{align}

Comment: @HudsonLima But what is the relevant of the representation matrix $\big[dx_p\big] $ and  the representation 
 matrix $[x]$ ? My guess is 
\begin{align} 
\big[dx_p\big]_{\partial ,\mathcal B} = \big[x\big]_{\mathcal V,\mathcal B}
\end{align}
where $\partial =\big(\partial_{u_1}|_p,\cdots,\partial_{u_m}|_p\big) $. Therefore 
\begin{align}
\big[\partial_{u_i}\big|_p \big]_{\mathcal A}=\big[x(v_i)\big]_{\mathcal B}
\end{align}
 Is that correct ?

Comment: This seems correct. Since $x$ is linear, via the canonical identification $T_pV\cong V$, we have $dx_p=x$.